# add dropdown list in jQuery datatable plugin rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, datatable

I am working on a project in asp.net boilerPlate and need to add dropdown list in datatable plugin for status rows.

```
 var dataTable = _projectsTable.DataTable({
            listAction: {
                ajaxFunction: _projectService.getAllCurrentProjects,
                inputFilter: function () {
                    return {
                        filter: $("#ProjectsTableFilter").val()
                    };
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    defaultContent: "",
                    data: "projectNo",
                    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        return '<a href=/App/Projects/Detail/' + row.id + '>' + (row.projectNo != null ? row.projectNo : "See Project" ) + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "projectName" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "client" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "asset" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "dueDate" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "projectManager" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "Status" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "" }
            ]

        });
```

and the statuses are:

```
   public static class ProjectConstants
    {
        public static string Completed = "Completed";
        public static string Cancelled = "Cancelled";
        public static string InProgress = "In Progress";
        public static string OnHold = "On Hold";
        public static string WaitingToStart = "Waiting To Start";
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how to change this line:  { defaultContent: "", data: "Status" }, to show the dropdown with mentioned statuses

Answer (score 1):

Change the code and apply below code:

```
var dataTable = _projectsTable.DataTable({
            listAction: {
                ajaxFunction: _projectService.getAllCurrentProjects,
                inputFilter: function () {
                    return {
                        filter: $("#ProjectsTableFilter").val()
                    };
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    defaultContent: "",
                    data: "projectNo",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return '<a href=/App/Projects/Detail/' + row.id + '>' + (row.projectNo != null ? row.projectNo : "See Project") + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "projectName" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "client" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "asset" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "dueDate" },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "projectManager" },
                {
                    defaultContent: "",
                    data: "Status",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var dropdown = '';
                        if (row != null) {
                            dropdown += '<select class="form-control">';
                            dropdown += '<option value="0">Select Status</option>';
                            dropdown += '<option value="Completed">Completed</option>';
                            dropdown += '<option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>';
                            dropdown += '<option value="InProgress">In Progress</option>';
                            dropdown += '<option value="OnHold">On Hold</option>';
                            dropdown += '<option value="WaitingToStart">Waiting To Start</option>';
                            dropdown += '</select>';
                        }
                        else {
                            dropdown = '<select class="form-control"><option value="0">Select Status</option></select>';
                        }
                        return dropdown;
                    }
                },
                { defaultContent: "", data: "" }
            ]

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with **@Purvesh** solution is that he **hard-coded** the dropDown. And why is that a problem?, you may be wondering. If tomorrow **@mah** decides to add a new status then he/she will need to make 2 changes, one on server-side and one on the client. So, to avoid that, you can get your status values via Ajax, like this:

**SERVER SIDE:**

These are your status:

```
public static class ProjectConstants
{
    public static string Completed = "Completed";
    public static string Cancelled = "Cancelled";
    public static string InProgress = "In Progress";
    public static string OnHold = "On Hold";
    public static string WaitingToStart = "Waiting To Start";
}
```

You can get them using **reflection**:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static object GetStatus()
{
    FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(ProjectConstants).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    var statusInfo = fields.Select(x => new { Text = x.GetValue(null).ToString(), Value = x.Name }).ToList();

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statusInfo);
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE:**

Get your status using **Ajax**:

```
function getStatus() {
    return  $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "wfDropDown.aspx/GetStatus",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
    }
```

Include a function to create your DropDown:

```
function createDropDown(data) {

    var html = '<select><option value="">Select a Stauts...</option>';

    for (var item of data) {

        html += '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
    }

    html += '</select>';

    return html;
}
```

Include your jQuery DataTable setup in a function (I did some modifications to your original code):

```
function initializeDataTable(dropDown) {

    var dataTable = _projectsTable.DataTable({
        listAction: {
            ajaxFunction: _projectService.getAllCurrentProjects,
            inputFilter: function () {
                return {
                    filter: $("#ProjectsTableFilter").val()
                };
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: "projectNo",
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<a href=/App/Projects/Detail/' + row.id + '>' + (row.projectNo != null ? row.projectNo : "See Project" ) + '</a>';
                }
            },
            { data: "projectName" },
            { data: "client" },
            { data: "asset" },
            { data: "dueDate" },
            { data: "projectManager" },
            {
                data: null, // "Status"
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return dropDown;
                }
            }
        ]

    });
}
```

And finally in your `$( document ).ready()` include this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    getStatus()
        .done(function (response) {

            var data = $.parseJSON(response.d);
            var dropDown = createDropDown(data);

            initializeDataTable(dropDown);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('There was something wrong trying to delete the Employee. Type: ' + textStatus + ". Description: " + errorThrown);
        });
});
```

This would be the final result:
[image]

Comment: *"I'm used to finish all my answers that way! Are you going to edit ALL of them?"* Although we technically should edit it out of all of them, I don't think we will, because that's largely a waste of time. However, you should not be ending any answers with that, as it doesn't belong. [Users are not supposed to add salutations to their posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). We'll leave it edited out of this answer, because it already was, and we'll ask you not to include this in your answers in the future.