# Dropdown button in row. Jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I make a drop-down button in a row and handle clicks on items in the drop-down list?

Example:

[image]

```
"columnDefs": [

{
            targets: 5,
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '<div class="relative"><a  dropdown-trigger="" class="pl-6 cursor-pointer text-slate-400 dark:text-white dark:opacity-80" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><ul dropdown-menu="" class="onediv z-100 min-w-44 text-size-sm shadow-soft-3xl duration-250 before:duration-350 before:font-awesome before:ease-soft before:text-5.5 dark:bg-gray-950 absolute top-0 right-0 left-auto m-0 mt-2 block origin-top cursor-pointer list-none rounded-lg border-0 border-solid border-transparent bg-white bg-clip-padding px-2 py-4 text-left text-slate-500 transition-all will-change-transform before:absolute before:right-5 before:left-auto before:z-40 before:text-white before:transition-all  sm:-mr-6 transform-dropdown-shown opacity-0 pointer-events-none before:top-0 transform-dropdown before:content-["\\f0d8"]"><li class="relative"><a id="one" class="py-1.2 lg:ease-soft clear-both block w-full whitespace-nowrap rounded-lg px-4 font-normal text-slate-500 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-slate-700 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:text-slate-700 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-200/80 dark:hover:text-slate-700 lg:duration-300" href="javascript:;">Edit Team</a></li><li class="relative"><a value="3" class="py-1.2 lg:ease-soft clear-both block w-full whitespace-nowrap rounded-lg px-4 font-normal text-slate-500 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-slate-700 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:text-slate-700 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-200/80 dark:hover:text-slate-700 lg:duration-300" href="javascript:;">Add Member</a></li><li class="relative"><a class="py-1.2 lg:ease-soft clear-both block w-full whitespace-nowrap rounded-lg px-4 font-normal text-slate-500 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-slate-700 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:text-slate-700 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-200/80 dark:hover:text-slate-700 lg:duration-300" href="javascript:;">See Details</a></li><li class="relative"><hr class="h-px my-2 bg-gradient-horizontal-dark"></li><li class="relative"><a class="py-1.2 text-danger lg:ease-soft clear-both block w-full whitespace-nowrap rounded-lg px-4 font-normal text-red-600 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-200/80 lg:duration-300" href="javascript:;">Remove Team</a></li></ul></div>'
 }]
```

This is adding a button and a list to each row

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'div.relative', function () {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();});
```

This is the list button click handler

I need to correctly handle clicks on the buttons in the drop-down list for each row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add dropdown list in jQuery datatable plugin rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63589023/add-dropdown-list-in-jquery-datatable-plugin-rows)

Comment: As well as [add dropdown list in jQuery datatable plugin rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63589023/add-dropdown-list-in-jquery-datatable-plugin-rows), you can research [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+show+dropdown+in+row+site:stackoverflow.com) for more possible solutions.

Comment: You can also provide a [mre] showing your attempt. See also [ask] and take a look at additional guidance in the [help].

Comment: I have a different problem.
I can open a drop-down list in each row by clicking the button. But I can't handle clicks in nested buttons in the list.

Comment: We need a [mre], please. Not just a screenshot, but a small example of code that we can copy, paste and run for ourselves, without needing to make changes. Something that shows the problem. See [What is a Stack Snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365).

Comment: Again, please see [ask], as well - for example, "_Help others reproduce the problem_".

Comment: Please can you provide a [mre] - something we can copy, paste, and run without needing to make changes.